# Bootstrap Collapse - multiple buttons - hide not working

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a 2 column page, HTML5/Bootstrap, columns stretched over the full page height. In the right column I'm trying to have a collapsible btn-group - each time you click on a button the target text collapses (this works fine) and if I click the same button the target text hides (works fine as well).

But if I click another 'collapse button' after I open the first target text, so than the one I clicked to open the first target text, let's call it #target1 - both the `<div>`s show, #target1 and target#2. But I want #target1 to hide and #target2 to show.

This is the code I have:

```
    <div id="right" class="col-sm-6 stretch-height" >
      <div id="menurow" class="row">
      <div id="icnavbar" class="col-sm-12 nopadding text-center">
      <div class="btn-group menugroup">
       <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#target1" class="btn-link"><img class="icmenu spin img-responsive" src="./img/ic_twitter.png" alt="follow us on twitter"/></button>
       <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#target2" class="btn-link"><img class="icmenu spin img-responsive" src="./img/ic_mail.png" alt="contact us"/></button>
     </div><!-- end btn-group menu-->

<div id="target1" class="collapse">
Some content 1
</div>
<div id="target2" class="collapse">
 </div><!-- end contactform div -->
Some content 2
</div>

</div><!-- end menu div-->
</div><!--end menurow-->
    </div><!--end right div-->
```

Comment: can you throw together a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Diego, i'm not sure but you can try imediate stop propagation like this example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/bdd6xt1b/20/

```
     $("body").on("click", "#teste", function(e) {
  alert("YOU SHALL NOT PASS!!!!!!!!!!!!");
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

$("body").on("click", "#teste", function() {
  alert("nao executar isto");
});
```